# Android app not installing after changing launcher activity

Tags: android

my problem is really weird , the application is installing after every run when the launcher activity is "NewsActivity" like this  :

```
       <activity android:name=".NewsActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".IntroActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".addFeedbackActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".FeedbacksActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SentRequestActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".RequestActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".TripDetailActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ShowTripsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".TripsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".AcceuilActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        </activity>
```

but when i change the launcher activity to "MainActivity" like this  :

```
      <activity android:name=".NewsActivity">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".IntroActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".addFeedbackActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".FeedbacksActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SentRequestActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".RequestActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".TripDetailActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ShowTripsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".TripsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".AcceuilActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

it dosent re install the app and it shows in console :

```
12/15 00:50:44: Launching 'app' on Pixel 2 API 25.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.yassineghr.travelmateapp/com.yassineghr.travelmateapp.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Waiting for process to come online...
Timed out waiting for process to appear on emulator-5554.
```

Comment: Uninstall the app manually from the emulator and then reinstall. Looks like a bug in your emulator.

Comment: i did but still the same problem

Comment: I am not sure what's going on. Does the order matter, I mean if you move the MainActivity to the top?

Comment: it's solved i just had to move Mainactivity to the top

Comment: Strange, glad it worked for you finally.